Placing someone's money in bank, and giving him the cost for placing his money in bank for bank statement
If I get some investor to put money in my bank account for 40 days, basically i need bank statement for study visa, and i have to pay the investor 5-10% of that money which he put in my bank for my bank statement of 40 days, after which he will take money out of bank. Is it permissible or not?
Note: It's not an investment, not a business loan, nothing. It's just he will place the money in bank for 40 days and we pay 5-10% of that to him. This is only for my bank statement to show for study visa, applying for United Kingdom.

So, just to clarify, this is him depositing his own money into an account that you don't have actual control of, just so you can claim the statement in your name?

You are borrowing money and paying interest on it, the ruling is the same as that for riba. The purpose or duration of the loan makes no difference.

Salam and welcome to ISlamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

Yes. This is him depositing his own money into an account that i don't have actual control of.
